# how to create a factory for a relationship between two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I want create a factory for a Relationship model which contains two attributes `followed_id` and `follower_id` but i have no idea how to do this, this is my factories file :

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end

  factory :relationship do
    # i need something like this
    # followed_id a_user.id
    # follower_id another_user.id
  end

end
```

**update**

what i want to do with this relationship factory is to test that if i destroy a user, all his relationships will be destroyed too, this is my test :

```
describe "relationships associations" do

let!(:relationship) { FactoryGirl.create(:relationship) }
it "should destroy associated relationships" do
  relationships = @user.relationships.to_a
  @user.destroy
  expect(relationships).not_to be_empty
  relationships.each do |relationship|
    expect(Relationships.where(id: relationship.id)).to be_empty
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

use [`association`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

```
  factory :relationship do |r| # 'r' is how you call relationship in the block
    ...
    r.association :followed #relationship is associated with followed user 
    #(i'm not sure how your application is set up, 
    #so you'll have to do this as best makes sense.  
    #is followed an attribute of user?  
    #then it would look like `r.association :user`
    f.association :follower #same here
  end
```

Comment: can you explain what you are doing here please ? and also what is r variable and followed and follower !!!

Comment: followed_id and follower_id are both attributes of user, so i'm not sure if i should do r.association :user two times or what !!!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience such "relationship" factory is rarely needed in test. Instead, "user_with_followers" and "user_following_some_ones" are often used.

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
  password "foobar"
  password_confirmation "foobar"

  factory :user_with_followers do
    ignore do
      followers_count 5
    end

    after_create do |user, evaluator|
      followers = FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, evaluator.followers_count)
      followers.each do |follower|
        follower.follow(user) # Suppose you have a "follow()" method in User
      end
  end

  factory :user_following_some_ones do
    # Do the similar
  end
end

# Use
FactoryGirl.create :user_with_followers
```

Comment: Billy, would you mind updating your answer to directly address his question? I think it would be nice to show that you _can_ simply create "relationship" instances like this.  Plus, I need to get my head better around the three options of: a) doing what you've shown, b) using the "association" mechanism, and c) simply providing references to the associated objects.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, IMO there is no "relationship" but "following" and "being followed" only :) We must specify the exact relationship and create extra users when using factory. My practice is to use  #c often, and sometimes #a. For #b I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

In the more recent versions of FactoryGirl, you should be able to do this:

```
factory :relationship do
  association :followed, :factory => :user
  association :follower, :factory => :user
end
```

What each of those two `association` lines does is set up a user instance (using your `:user` factory), and then assign to `followed` or `follower` of the current relationship instance.

Note that you need to specify the factory unless the association name and factory name are the same.

**Update:**

When creating the Relationship, specify `:followed` or `:follower` (whichever is applicable to you). Otherwise, it creates new user records for each of those and uses them.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:relationship, :followed => @user)
```

Comment: What's the indication that the factory doesn't work? Does it say there is a validation error in your model or does it give you a FactoryGirl specific error?

Comment: i create a relation with factory like this : let!(:relationship) { FactoryGirl.create(:relationship) } then i do relationships = @user.relationships.to_a, finally when i test that : expect(relationships).not_to be_empty it fails and it says that is empty

Comment: Do: `FactoryGirl.create(:relationship, :followed => @user)` (or `:follower`) to create a relationship for `@user`. Otherwise, it creates a new user record and uses that.

You might be also be preloading `@user.relationships` before the relationship is created. You can try `@user.relationships.reload` to reload the association.

If that is still not the problem, can we see the rest of your test?

Comment: when i do FactoryGirl.create(:relationship, :followed => @user) it fails : Factory not registered: relationship

Comment: Regarding your last comment, can you try reloading your test environment? It seems that it cannot find the `:relationship` factory definition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37818/discussion-between-medbo-and-kristinalim)